# Power Automate Try multiple API Keys until success

Tags: power-automate

I have a power automate flow that receives POST data from a webhook (using `When a HTTP Request is Received`). I have a step in this flow that does:

**HTTP**

```
Type: GET
URI: https://api.EXAMPLE.com/public/v1/{DOC_ID}/download
Headers: Authorization: API-Key: {API_KEY}
```

This flow is currently working great but it looks like this flow will have to be attached to more 15 more webhooks, performing the same operation on each. The problem is that because these webhooks are in different workspaces, the `API_KEY` is different for each one, and there is no unique workspace/environment ID included, so I cannot have a case statement that is like:

```
if ENVIRONMENT == 'Group1':
    API_KEY = 123456
elseif ENVIRONMENT == 'Group2'
    API_KEY = ABCDEF
elseif... x15
```

I can of course create 15 duplicates of this flow and change the API_KEY but if I have to perform a change to this flow, I have to do it 15 times. My goal is to have 1 flow for this process.

Is there a way to provide a list of API_KEY's and have Power Automate attempt to use each API_KEY and break the loop once it is successfully downloaded?

When you use an invalid API_KEY, Power Automate returns statusCode 401 with body:

> {   "type": "authentication_error",   "detail": "Invalid key." }

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but as of right now, your question is far too high level to answer.  Can you zero in on a specific section in your flow?  Show us something, that may help us.

Comment: @Skin I included the part of the flow I am trying to loop through. I want to perform the HTTP download step iterating through multiple API Keys until the statuscode != 401

Comment: You haven’t shown anything, show us your flow. I’m not going to recreate something on my side, I need to see your flow and I’ll tell you what you need to change.